# Mat-select not showing the selected value

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6, angular-material-6, formgroups

[image: This is what I get]When my edit form is loaded I want to fill the form Array with initial values.
My drop down selection option got disabled but it doesn't show in the mat-select.

```
let selectedSpecs = this.editData.element.specifications;

this.spec = this.specForm.get('spec') as FormArray;

if (selectedSpecs.length != 0){
  let selectedAttributeIds = [];
  selectedSpecs.forEach((spec, i) => {
    let attribute;
    attribute = {'id': spec.itemDetailId, 'itemId':this.editData.element.itemId, 'name': spec.name};

    this.spec.push(this.formBuilder.group({
      attribute: attribute,
      attributeSpec: spec.description
    }));

    selectedAttributeIds.push(spec.itemDetailId);

  });

  let attributes = [];
  this.selectedCatAttributes.forEach((tempattribute) => {
    let selected;
    if (selectedAttributeIds.includes(tempattribute.id)) {
      selected = true;
    }else {
      selected = false;
    }
    attributes.push(new Attribute(tempattribute, !selected));
  });

  this.attributeList.next(attributes);


}





<div formArrayName="spec" *ngFor="let spec of specForm.get('spec')['controls']; let i= index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <mat-card class="addShadow">
          <button style="float: right" mat-icon-button (click)="removeSpec(i)"><mat-icon class="specClear">cancel</mat-icon></button>


          <mat-form-field class="spec">
            <mat-select placeholder="Select Attribute" formControlName="attribute" (selectionChange)="selectedOption($event.value,i)">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let attribute of attributeList | async; let index = index" [value]="attribute.attribute" [disabled]="!attribute.allowed">
                {{attribute.attribute.name}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field class="spec">
            <input matInput placeholder="Specification" formControlName="attributeSpec">
          </mat-form-field>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How can I show the initial values in the drop downs. I am using form arrays. I have tried to use [value]  as well as [compareWith] none of this worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

I tried so many times and figured out a way to solve this problem. I used [compareWith] to solve the issue. Here is my solution.

This is the method I called in [compareWith].

```js
attributeDisplay(attribute1, attribute2) {
  if (attribute1.id == attribute2.id) {
    return attribute1.name;
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

Here is my HTML.

```html
<mat-form-field class="spec">
  <mat-select
    placeholder="Select Attribute"
    formControlName="attribute"
    (selectionChange)="selectedOption($event.value,i)"
    [compareWith]="attributeDisplay"
  >
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let attribute of attributeList | async; let index = index"
      [value]="attribute.attribute"
      [disabled]="!attribute.allowed"
    >
      {{attribute.attribute.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the result!  This part (`compareFn`) is not documented in official docs for multiple select ‍♂️

Comment: Nice one. I did not know about this function.

Comment: When the selected value is different from the mat options, the select will display an empty value. This compareWith attribute helps to solve that !, thank you :)

Comment: got a similar issue, the value (my object) was in my formcontrol but was not displayed properly, this helped me! thx!

Comment: @Samasha, this has solved my problem. But my question though is why it is needed to use this attribute? It increases load on UI processing and ultimately adding lags to UX.

Comment: Stupid documentation didn't tell about this important nuance